# Change value of multiple select2 based on value in another select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a select 2 which has a list of values and I want to be able to use it to populate a number of the select 2 dropdowns based on the initial selection.

```
<select id='fonts'>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Times">Times</option>
<option value="Arial">Arial</option>
<option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
</select>

<select name="s1" class='font'>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Times">Times</option>
<option value="Arial">Arial</option>
<option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
</select>

<select name="s2" class='font'>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Times">Times</option>
<option value="Arial">Arial</option>
<option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
</select>

<select name="s3" class='font'>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Times">Times</option>
<option value="Arial">Arial</option>
<option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
</select>
```

When not using select2 this is working using:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#fonts').on('change', function() {
            if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {

                var font=$(this).val();

                if (font!="") {
                    $( ".font" ).each(function() {
                        // $(this).select2('val', font);
                        $(this).val(font);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

However, as soon as I introduce select2 then the values do not change. Select2 is not loaded over AJAX etc which a lot of other answers are referring to.

I have tried:

```
$(this).select2('val', font);
```

but again, that does not work.

How can I update the value of all the secondary select2?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I figured this out, there is no need to call anything select2 related so just val is fine but I was also missing a second method to 'notify' that the select2 had updated

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#fonts').on('change', function() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {

            var font=$(this).val();

            if (font!="") {
                $( ".font" ).each(function() {
                    $(this).val(font);
                    $(this).trigger('change');
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```